# Formatting date field in KendoUI Grid coming as object

Tags: kendo-grid, symfony-2.3

I am trying to format a date field in KendoUI Grid where the field is coming as an object:

```
"callStart":{"date":"2014-01-24 12:04:36","timezone_type":3,"timezone":"Europe\/Berlin"}
```

I have tried:

```
{ field: "callStart", title: "Fecha", width: "100px", format: "{0:yyyy-MM-dd}" }
```

but still showing:

```
[object Object]
```

Any idea?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't know if you already solved it, but I'll answer late anyways. The reason why it's not working is because you are probably trying to bind the entire object `callStart` into the field column. The field expects only a date object, but you are *not* giving it one.

Also, your object seems to still be in JSON string format, you need to parse the object out as a first step (if it really is just raw JSON). Then the next step, you can:

1. Parse `callStart` on the columns themselves (with kendo Templates)
2. Parse `callStart` on the datasource itself through its schema

---

Option 1: Parse on the column field itself using a template

```
{ 
   field: "callStart", 
   title: "Fecha", 
   width: "100px", 
   template: "#= kendo.toString(kendo.parseDate(callStart.date, 'yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss'), 'MM/dd/yyyy') #"
}
```

The advantage of this option is that your data source object still maintains its original form, but filtering and sorting may get a bit tricky.

---

Option 2: Parse the object through the dataSource schema

```
 var gridDS = new kendo.data.DataSource({
     data: result,
     schema: {
         parse: function (result) {
             for (var i = 0; i < result.length; i++) {
                 var resultItem = result[i];
                 resultItem.callStart = kendo.parseDate(result[i].callStart.date, 'yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss');
             }
             return result;
         }
     },
     //etc...
 });
```

Each data source object goes through the parse function and you can do whatever processing you need to do to turn it into a JS date or kendo Date object. The advantage is that you can control the exact type for that column and makes filtering/sorting easier.

You'll probably have to do some tweaking to get your desired output, but these are the general options you need to pick from.

Comment: I have already solved it using your first suggestion, but thanks for your help, the second one is very interesting too...